# Unable to add widget to FlowPanel

Tags: java, gwt, errai

I've been trying to figure out what is wrong with my

```
@Inject
@DataField
FlowPanel panel;

// Here's the REST callback:    
public void onSuccess(StuffResultItemDTO stuffResultItem) {

       for (StuffItemDTO item : stuffResultItem.getStuff()) {
           LOG.info(item.toString()); // No problem data is here  
           ResultItem w = resultInstance.get();
           w.setModel(item);
           panel.add(w);
       }

       // Producer
       stuff.setCursor(stuffResultItem.getCursor());
}
```

This has been my problem for quite a while now. The catch is if I manually add something in the `FlowPanel` the widget is shown.

So the panel really can inject widgets into it (like manually adding the ResultItem).

The real pain here is the for-loop code and the injection of `ResultItem` there.

Comment: what happens ? Do you get an error message ? Check the HTML with Dev Tools.

Comment: Yeah I've checked with the HTML, and as inspected the data is not rendered, yet the actual POJO is ok and its there returned by the method.

Comment: The problem was with handler registration being registered every time the page is loaded